# What is the origin of the Bible code theory?

Tags: tanach, mysticism-kabbalah

What is now known as gematria has been practiced since the earliest days of the Hebrew alphabet.

The 22 (a significant number in itself) letters were used to record not just linguistic but also numerical information, yet the idea of a transcendent mathematical system defining the operations of the universe seems to date no earlier than the Enlightenment.

Notwithstanding, characters like Rabbi Cohen in the movie π by Darren Aronofsky make it seem as if the idea of a magical Code had always existed — so, what is the earliest citable example of the Tanach or Torah in its entirety being considered as an encrypted secret code?

Comment: Hafoch ba vehafoch ba dekula ba. Turn the Torah over and over for everything is in it. (Avot 5:26).

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: There are two overlapping issues here. One is that the Torah is full of infinite wisdom at every level. The other is that the particular Torah Code examples are meaningful. The first could be true and the second not.

Comment: Zamir Cohen is a disgrace who tries to "prove" the Torah using theories like mesmerism that were already proven false in the days of Ben Franklin.

Comment: The first Rabbi I know of who did something like Bible Codes is Rabbi Michoel Ber Weissmandel.

Answer (score 3):

There is a generally discredited book called "Bible Codes", which posit that strings of gap *n* in the Torah spell out words that are prophetic. This answer is **not** supporting this work, nor do I think the question is asking about it.

The question is asking if the Torah is an "encrypted secret code", a very vague statement, and the gist of the question is that the Torah is in some way the blueprint of creation, involving (at least in part) numerical secrets, including the gematria.

The idea of the Torah being the blueprint of creation is as old as Sinai. The Midrash Bereshit Rabbah 1:1 explains that Hashem

> מַבִּיט בַּתּוֹרָה וּבוֹרֵא אֶת הָעוֹלָם
>
> looked into the Torah and created the world

The verses this is based on and how it is derived is explained there. The Midrash Tanchuma 1:1 explains on the similar point that if a single letter is changed in the Torah it ruins everything:

> כֵּיצַד? כָּתוּב בָּהּ, וְלֹא תְחַלְּלוּ אֶת שֵׁם קָדְשִׁי (ויקרא כב,
> לב), אִם אַתָּה עוֹשֶׂה חֵי״‎ת הֵ״‎א, אַתָּה מַחֲרִיב אֶת הָעוֹלָם
>
> For example, it is written in the Torah: Profane not My Holy Name
> (Lev. 22:2); but if you should change the het in the word yehallelu
> (“profane”) into a heh, the word would read “praise,” and you would
> thereby destroy the world.

The first lessons in 2 of the most ancient and important Midrashic works, penned in the [courts of the unbroken chain of Torah teachers back to Moshe](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/901656/jewish/Introduction-to-Mishneh-Torah.htm); all the *gematriot* and kabbalistic explanations of the points you are asking about are elaborating on this point: **that the Torah is the blueprint of the world, designed by the Artist of the world.**

---

See Rabbi Tatz's *Worldmask*, which elaborates in great detail in Chapter 1:

> The Torah is the cause and the world is the result

Quoting the same tradition, with the Zohar as his source:

> קוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא אִסְתָּכַּל בְּאוֹרַיְיתָא, וּבָרָא עָלְמָא
>
> Hashem looked into the Torah and created the world

He explains that the existence of the entire world and every one of its details is created from Hashem's word, which is

> *the means, the mechanism of Creation*. Each word spoken by Hashem in
> creating the world crystallized into the object it described

He extends this to not just the Written Torah, but the Oral Torah. Quoting the Talmudic story of "*lo bashamayim hee"*:

> And now we can open a startling new awareness: if Torah lives in the
> minds and personalities of its Sages, *that is where the causative,
> primary energy of the world is to be found.* This most profound idea
> means that Hashem's Torah *is* the consciousness of the Sages of
> *Torah she'b'al peh*. It has been given to us; it is no longer in Heaven, so to speak, and we are partners in Creation in the deepest
> sense possible.

So he has made our case, that the entire existence of reality is rooted in the Torah, based on the ancient sources quoted here. The reason why this idea gets more technical after the enlightenment is because it was the enlightenment that changed the way we view *the world*, not the way we view the Torah. We began to see that the world itself has many secrets; physical laws, distant galaxies, unbeknownst phenomena like inflation and speciation - there are many things we discovered that are not written *explicitly* in the Torah.

However, this ancient and most fundamental Torah principle that the Torah is the blueprint of creation means that these matters are all in the Torah too, and the fact that we cannot see them means they are encoded/encrypted. Gematria is one possibility, but generally speaking it is a secret matter, so not much more can be said.

Comment: it also proves that Moses did not paraphrase or add/subtract a single letter from the Torah

Comment: This is not an answer. You didn't say that the Bible Codes are part of our Mesorah, just that they could be.